# Class inheriting from ActiveSupport::Subscriber does not get loaded in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activesupport

I've added an ActiveSupport subscriber in `app/subscribers`

```
class SubscriptionCreationSubscriber < ActiveSupport::Subscriber
  attach_to :created

  def subscription(event)
    puts 'Subscription created'
  end
end
```

This is intended to run whenever a `subscription.created` event is broadcast.
The event is broadcast in a model as a callback like this:

```
def broadcast_event
  ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument 'subscription.created', subscription: self
end
```

When I check in the console for `ActiveSupport::Subscriber` descendants, all I get is

```
[ActionMailer::LogSubscriber, ActiveJob::Logging::LogSubscriber, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber, Lograge::RequestLogSubscriber, ActionView::LogSubscriber, ActionController::LogSubscriber, ActiveModelSerializers::Logging::LogSubscriber, ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber]
```

The folder itself is getting loaded, however, it seems like the constant isn't. How do I get it to load? Or alternately, how do I selectively eager load a file/folder?

Comment: What is `:created`?

Comment: Should have added in the question, I'm broadcasting an event called 'subscription.created' in a callback in a model

Comment: can you show also the instrumentation code?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, I've added it in the question. The code works in console as long as `SubscriptionCreationSubscriber` is called once in the console and it appears in the list of descendants. But as I said, it is not loaded in the console at start

Comment: @TheGeorgeous rails "Autoloads" the constants so the first time you call it it looks it up and loads it, prior to that it has no usage and thus what you are seeing. If you want it to load all the constants you can do so with `config.eager_load = true` https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#eager-loading

Comment: @engineersmnky, I'm aware of that, but I'm really trying to get away with not loading the entire app and eager loading only a certain file/folder similar to how a gem would do it.

Comment: @TheGeorgeous a gem would use `require` you could place this in an initializer if you'd like